# is iOS background mode needed if app works when suspended?

Tags: ios, background

I need my iPhone app to do some tasks in the background when it's suspended, but I don't need to do any tasks after it's turned off. Do I need to settle `UIBackgroundMode`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to execute code continuously in the background state, you need to register for a given UIBackgroundMode.

See [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios) or [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) for a good source on this.

However if you just wish to perform a single background task (task completion), you don't need a background mode.

In response to your comment below, I will try to be clear:

In iOS, even in iOS 7, it's not possible to run arbitrary code when your application is in a background state indefinitely.

In simple English, - you can't just run any code you like in the background for as long as you like.

There are rules.

These rules have been relaxed somewhat in iOS 7, but it's still not totally unrestricted.

Consider your situation: You have a timer that wants to call a method on a continuous basis.

Now consider the UIBackgroundModes available (which allow you to run in the background in various situations):

**audio** - Only for audio based apps.

**location** - Only if you app is location aware, does specific location tasks

**voip** - VOIP (Skype etc)

**fetch** (Background fetch - a new iOS 7 API where the system gives you application moments to grab new content **when it** sees fit.

**remote-notification** - new in iOS 7, when the device receives a remote push notification with a certain payload, it will resume and execute a certain block of code.

**newsstand-content** - Only for newsstand apps

**external-accessory** - Only for external accessories to communicate with the device

**bluetooth-peripheral** Only for external BT accessories to communicate with the device (fitbit)

As you can see if you don't fall into one of these categories you can't use these modes.
If you misuse the modes Apple won't approve your application.

Finally we have 'Background task completion'

This is a way to use a UIBackgroundTask to execute any code you want in the background! Including timers that call methods! - One problem though...

This is supposed to be for 'task completion' (Facebook uploads that aren't complete, saving or processing data that should be done before the app suspends even though the user pressed the home button).

Sounds good, **but** you can only run in the background using this method for a maximum of 10 minutes. If you go over this time limit iOS will immediately kill your application.

So as you can see, there is no way for your application to be approved on the store and constantly run in the background with a timer that calls your method.

Sorry about that.

If you want to learn more check [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html) out.

Comment: I have got NSTimer which calls a method, which checks if it's needed to publish a notification. Do i need to turn on UIBackGroundMode?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm creating timer app. The last question, if u know the answer, if it's possible to show notification every 90 second after app was suspended?

Comment: @serg_ov just so I understand clearly, are you saying that when the user presses the home button and 'closes' (suspends) your app, you want to pop a local notification (like when you receive a text message) every 90 seconds, that keeps happening until the user relaunches your app?

Comment: I understand my friend, here is what I would say. 1) Apple will not approve an app like that on the store, because under their guidelines I think they would deem it as 'intrusive' (cause the user a problem) - I know you think the user will want to know of their timer, but Apple won't! .... but with that said, there really is no mechanism or way to do what you want to do with the current API restrictions, unfortunately, and if you "pretend" you need one of the background modes and don't use it for it's expected purpose they will block your app, look into UILocalNotification, maybe it is a help

Answer (score -2):

Use the location service and set NO location manager "pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically" property.